# DB2: Function to merge 3 column output

Tags: sql, db2

I have below records in table1

```
c1  c2  c3
----------
A   B   C
```

How to merge c1 c2 and c3 so the output would like

A B C 
with space in between the output 
I used concat function but its not taking 3 arguments 
like

```
select concat (c1,c2,c3) from table1
```

I cant run `select * from table1` as I want output in one column

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This works in z/OS versions at least:

```
select c1 concat ' ' concat c2 concat ' ' concat c3
```

Get to know the DB2 [documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.intro/src/tpc/db2z_concatenationofstrings.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the solution as well as the DB2 documentation, It really helped me.

Comment: You can also use `||` in place of `concat`.

Answer (score 9):

I came across the same problem recently, I used the || (double pipes) in order to concat to columns.

I also had to write a wrapper to in my query to overcame the issue.

Below is a snippet of what my queries looked like in the end.

```
select a1 || a2 as a2, a3 || a4 as a4 --wrapper 2
from (
select '"service":"' as a1,a2, '","total":' as a3, a4 --wrapper 1
from (
select distinct(a2),count(*) as a4 
from abc.table
group by a2 
order by a2)
);
```

Below is what the ouput was from the query:

```
"service":"ABC" , "total":123
```

Comment: pipes was they way to go for me!

Answer (score 6):

try this.

```
select concat(concat (c1,c2),c3) from table1
```

Comment: This cancat is not working in my db2 v-9.7, is there any way to concat more than 3 column results

Comment: I just tried the following command in DB2
`select concat(c1,concat(c2, c3)) from table1`

Comment: Thanks. I am still having one issue on the result I am getting the output as `ABC` I want this to be displayed as `A B C` with the spaces in between in the single column. I tried couple of options as `select concat(c1, '', concat(c2, c3)) from table1` but its giving me error as `SQL0206N  " " is not valid in the context where it is used.  SQLSTATE=42703`

Comment: concat can be used as an operator, and thus combine more then 2 values!  see my answer for example

Answer (score 1):

I had a issue with converting from SQL to DB2. This page helped, but I ended up making a little change:

```
SELECT
RTRIM(C1) || '' || C2 as CFULL
FROM TABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT C1 CONCAT '' CONCAT ( C2 CONCAT '' CONCAT C3) FROM TABLENAME`

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers, instead try adding some information that explains why your code answers the OP's question.